# Loop over subset of rows, starting from a specific row PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there a way in which I could loop over a subset of rows in a table, starting from a specific row, in PL/SQL?
For example I have a table of 20 rows and I want to work on all the rows from row 4 onwards. After I've finished one iteration, I reorder the table before iterating again.

Comment: Oracle tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column to specify the ordering or row number.

Comment: ... _why_ do you want to do this?  Usually, looping is the wrong idea in SQL to begin with, as well as caring about "order" in numerous cases.

Comment: I'm trying to write a program, based on a genetic algorithm approach, in PL SQL to compare the results, performance wise, with a version I've written in C#. I need looping to simulate iterations over the population.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality directly in Oracle. But there are cursors. They are great, look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html) or [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/prog2/ch06_02.htm) for more details.

If You are talking of PL/SQL though, You can easily implement it. First thing You need to worry about is the ORDER BY clause of Your query - if You want to process rows from row 4, You should know what order is correct.

Second thing is how to count first four rows. You can do it by some i counter variable in loop, or directly in query (which will be probably faster).

Below some example:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR employees_in_10_cur
    IS
    SELECT 
        rownum,
        *
    FROM 
        employees
    WHERE 
        department_id = 10
    ORDER BY 
        employee_id
    ;
BEGIN
    FOR employee_rec IN employees_in_10_cur
    LOOP
        IF employee_rec.rownum >= 4 THEN
            -- Do something here
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (employee_rec.employee_id);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thank you very much. One more question tho, how much do multiple `begin` `end` blocks influence the performance ?

Comment: Actually, it's not the `BEGIN ... END` blocks that influence the performance, but the code run inside it...

Comment: Glad that this helped You. As for perfoemance question, I do not belive they have any measurable impact. They serve more logistic purpose - to divide code into blocks, which can have their own exception handling and so on. Hey, somebody even measured it! Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833481/do-nested-blocks-have-any-performance-impact-in-pl-sql-procedures). :)